# Title on Action Bar displaying garbage value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-actionbar

I'm trying to display the name of the `Listview` item on the action bar as it's title on the next activity screen using intents.

Here is my code.

**MathematicsDBEntry.java**

```
public class MathematicsDBEntry extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String newActionBarTitle = i.getStringExtra("Position");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(newActionBarTitle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mathematics_dbentry);


    }

}
```

**MathsActivity.java**

```
public class MathsActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maths);

        // storing string resources into Array
        String[] math_data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.maths_list_data);

        ListView listView = getListView();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, math_data);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        //Toast.makeText(this, textView.getText().toString() + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MathematicsDBEntry.class);
        intent.putExtra("Position", textView.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

But all I get is the garbage value shown below.

[image: http://imgur.com/Bbljmlx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()) method of `TextView` to get the data from it.

You need to change:

```
intent.putExtra("Position", textView.toString());
```

to:

```
intent.putExtra("Position", textView.getText().toString());
```